# Difference between Class A and class Class1

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to do this C++ tutorial. I am a beginner in C++ programming. I don't get why they use `setValue` and `getValue` in `class Class1` and not setClass1. In the other tutorial they use `setA` and `getA` in the class `class Class1`. Here are the codes:

```
    class Class1 {
    int i;
public:
    void setValue( int value ) { i = value; }
    int getValue() { return i; }
};
```

the second code is:

```
    class A{
    int ia;
public:// accessor method because they are used to access a private date member
    void setA ( const int a);
    int getA ()const;
    int getA ();
};
```

Please help...

Comment: Simply because they are different classes, maybe designed to do different things (even though the look similar), and maybe designed and implemented by different people. Just because two classes may _look_ similar doesn't mean they are.

Comment: @nickecarlo sorry I did not get your question...

Comment: They can be named whatever you want.  setValue setBlahBlah, setFruitBasket...anything.  The general best practice is to name them the same as your field name.  setI, getI in the case of Class1 and setIa, getIa in the case of ClassA

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Also, the names are completely arbitrary. I could call the functions `blah` and `foo`, and that would be fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg will they still mean the same thing?

Comment: No, and that's one of the points. Two unrelated classes are completely unrelated, no matter how similar the look.

Comment: so getAnyname and setAnyName?

Comment: You don't even need `set` and `get`. The people who designed the classes decided to do that just to make the functions more clear, but that's not a requirement.

Comment: nickecarlo meant that this question has nothing to do with C, so I've edited it accordingly.

Comment: @tacp the two codes are in different files. I was confused on why they use the same name in get and set with the class name, and different get and set name on the other class. Will the set and get names affect the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names are arbitrary, you can use any function names you wish (subject to language rules, of course).

However, although you *can* use `xyzzy()` and `plugh()` as getter and setter, it's not really a good idea.

You should use something that indicates the intent of the call, such as `getTemperature()` or `setVelocity()`. And these don't even have to map one-to-one to internal fields since encapsulation means the internal details should not be exposed.

By that, I mean you may have a `getTemperatureC()` for returning the temperature in Celsius even though the internal field is stored as Kelvins:

```
double getTemperatureC(void)     { return kelvins - 273.15; }
void   setTemperatureC(double t) { kelvins = t + 273.15; }
```

(or a getter/setter may use arbitrarily complex calculations).

Using `getA()` for a class `A` may well cause you trouble when you create class `B` to inherit from `A` but this is outside the scope of the language. But it's good programming practice to follow the guideline above (functions should indicate intent rather than internals).

Answer (score 1):

> I was confused on why they use the same name in get and set with the class name, and different get and set name on the other class. Will the set and get names affect the code?

The answer is **No.**

`getter` and `setter` are usually called `accessor` and `mutators` in a class. They are just member functions named according to some convention, easy for people who read the code to understand the purpose of those functions, so it is like common sense to name those member function starting with `get` if you try to access the member variables and starting with `set` if you try to change some member variables. The names can be any valid identifier.

So `setValue` or `setA` are just identifiers for those member functions. It will not affect the code.

Meanwhile, different class can have the same named getter or setters since those function names are in different class scope.